# What is incorrect in the constructor call of this c++ class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

The following code is compiling but keeps crashing unexpectedly in QtCreator. Where am I going wrong here?

Here is the definition of my `MainWindow` class.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* ellipse;

    std::vector<SimplePoint_2> vecpoints;
    CGAL::Qt::PointsGraphicsItem< std::vector<SimplePoint_2>  > gpoints; //The graphical representation of the above point vector
};
```

Here is the call to the constructor of the Main Window class

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    gpoints(&vecpoints)
{        
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    ellipse = scene->addEllipse(0,10,100,100);

    std::cout << "Pushing points into the vector" << std::endl;
    vecpoints.push_back(SimplePoint_2(1,1));
    vecpoints.push_back(SimplePoint_2(50,4));  
}
```

When I comment out the member item `gpoints` and the corresponding `gpoints(&vecpoints)` from the constructor call, the code runs perfectly.

So it looks like I am calling the constructor of `gpoints` incorrectly. 
What is wrong?

Note that the constructor of the templated class

`CGAL::Qt::PointsGraphicsItem` needs a pointer to an iterable container, (in this case a vector) according to the library I am using.

Comment: Do you get a compile-time error or run-time?

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Run time error. "The program unexpectedly crashed"

Comment: Are you able to debug your code? On which line does it crash?

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to initialise the `gpoints` field using the address of `vecpoints` which hasn't been initialised yet. Try removing it from initialiser list and put that initialisation after pushing back points to `vecpoints`

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury `vecpoints` is declared before `gpoints` so that should be fine, unless the code shown differs from the real one.

Comment: The code is the same as this one. Is this related to some behaviours of qt cplus plus extensions i may not beaware of?

Comment: @AntonSavin Is this because according to my code I am setting 'gpoints' EQUAL TO '&vecpoints'? When in actuality i  should be passing this to gpoints constructor? If that is the case how shoild I call gpoints' constructor properly?

Comment: @smilingbuddha Your code looks fine. You should run under debugger, step through your code and see what's going on. Again, make sure `vecpoints` is declared above `gpoints` in the `MainWindow`.

Comment: You may get better answers with a QT tag.